# Launch singleTop between multiple activites

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I have some trouble with understanding of singleTop concept with launching Activities.

we have some activities A,B,C,D and singleTop is defined with activity B in manifest file.

As i read if we will go A->B->C->D->D than instance of D activity will not create and D will be top on the stack.

But if we will go A->B->C->D->B than what will happen?
Which activity will be launch and which will be top on stack?

Please suggest.

Comment: for complete understanding of singleTop, read [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. I read your given link but still have confusion. Can you please tell me with above scenario ?

Comment: singleTop is same like standard, in you case A->B->C->D->B : when redirect from D to B , B will not create instance of activity because its already in stack so in stack history looks like B->C->D->A.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launch mode *singleTop* applies only for Activities that are on **top of the stack**.

Let the stack be `A-B-C-D` (D on top) and D is an activity with *singleTop* launch mode. If you add another instance to this stack then D will not be instantiated again and the existing instance of D will receive a callback to `onNewIntent()`.

Stack: `A-B-C-D`

But if the stack was like `A-B-C-D-B` (B on top) and then you launch an activity of D, then it will simply create a new instance of D and put at the top of the stack. This is because D was not at the top of the stack.

Stack: `A-B-C-D-B-D`

Comment: Thanks Sir for your valuable reply.
One last question ...
If the stack is A-B-C-D (D on top) and B is an activity with singleTop launch mode and i launch Activity B from Activity D then ?

Comment: Stack: A-B-C-D-B